# Why doesn't installing GRUB on MBR destroy the partition table?

Tags: hard-drive, grub, mbr

I have read that my partition table is stored in the MBR. And write operations are performed sector-wise i.e, even if you want to change just a few bytes of a sector you need to overwrite entire contents of the sector. So when installing GRUB on MBR, why doesn't it destroy my partition table?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The software reads the original sector; updates it in memory; then writes out the updated sector.

On Linux, this is actually done by the OS itself, so GRUB doesn't need to worry about sectors – it can just issue a 440-byte write, and the OS will read/modify/write the whole 512-byte sector accordingly. (The job of an OS *is* to abstract away the inconvenient hardware details.) But if the OS didn't do this, then GRUB could still do the same read/modify/write thing on its own.

This "read/modify/write" pattern is not limited to just the MBR – it's also how you're able to change individual bytes within a file, even though they're also stored in disk sectors. The OS will read the corresponding sector from disk, update it with your changes, then write the new sector back.

Comment: Isn't read-modify-write done by the hard drive firmware, not software on the OS?

Comment: Both. The disk interface only has commands for writing _whole_ logical sectors, so writes smaller than a sector have to be r/m/w'd by the OS – it literally has no way to issue a byte-level write to the disk. (At least this is true for ATA and SCSI, as far as I know.) On the other hand, if you have a disk which has e.g. 4K physical sectors but still emulates traditional 512b logical sectors, then yes, the disk's firmware will r/m/w the whole physical 4K sector when it needs to handle the emulated 512b write operation.